# static statement at the head of .cpp file not called

Tags: c++, static

I have a class file in the common foundations code of the company called Receiver.

One of the first lines of the cpp file of this class (after the #include lines) says:

```
static const bool res = ReceiverFactory::registerCreator(Receiver::getProjectReceiverName(), Receiver::create );
```

On one of the application that use this code, I can see that this line runs when app is starting.

On a similar application this is not the case. This line does not run at all. I need to explicitly construct an object of that class to get this line to execute.

Is that a VS solution/project configuration issue? Any other ideas?

Comment: Will that be a `#ifdef` case?

Comment: I vaguely remember that a static variable may be instanciated between program start and first access to the variable. Maybe you never read from `res` so the compiler did not feel the need to instanciate it while being 100% conforming?

Comment: Are you sure that the *.cpp file has been linked? (Are there other symbols from this file that you are successfully using?) If it has been linked, is it possible that this has been removed due to a lack of references to that variable?

Comment: @MichaelAaronSafyan the file is sure being linked since I can instantiate the class at the head of my main class

Comment: Then it sounds like you are running into the lack of usage issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the linker is eliding or deferring the evaluation of this statement due to the lack of references to it. This problem has already been solved before, though, so you may want to take advantage of existing solutions. One solution is to have a list of initialization routines that are explicitly iterated through in the main() method on initialization. This is more or less the approach taken by Google's REGISTER_MODULE_INITIALIZER function that is in the Chromium source code:

http://src.chromium.org/svn/releases/3.0.190.2/src/third_party/cld/base/googleinit.h

With that code in particular, it's possible to do:

```
REGISTER_MODULE_INITIALIZER(register_creator, {
    ReceiverFactory::registerCreator(
         Receiver::getProjectReceiverName(), &Receiver::create);
});
```

And then explicitly initialize this (and other modules) in main, with:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  RUN_MODULE_INITIALIZERS();
  // ...
}
```

There are other ways to do this kind of static initialization, as well, such as `__attribute__((constructor))` (though that is non-standard) or creating a non-POD object statically whose constructor function does the intialization that you want, for example:

```
namespace initialization {
namespace {

  class DoStaticInitialization {
    public:
      DoStaticInitialization() {
          ReceiverFactory::registerCreator(
             Receiver::getProjectReceiverName(), &Receiver::create);
      }
  };
  DoStaticInitialization initializer_instance_;

}
}
```